# Netbeans No Main classes found

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

Yesterday I downloaded JDK and Netbeans as my IDE. When I attempt to create my first ever Java project, I get

> "no main class found"

as shown by the screenshot below [image]

What do I do for the correct setup please?

I have since clicked on Properties>Run

[image]

and still have the same problem.

The syntax errors are shown in the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Would it have anything to do with my setup of src folder?

[image]

Comment: In your screenshots there are a couple of statements underlined in red - typically indicating syntax errors. I would suggest you hover your mouse over these (or click on the red exclamation icon in the margin and see what they say. That may be enough to help you solve the problem yourself, or otherwise please add that detail to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your Project in the project explorer

Click on properties

Click on Run

Make sure your Main Class is the one you want to be the entry point.

Click OK.

Run Project

Comment: I have tried this but no luck im afraid!